# Probability Question: In what region must the center lie to ensure that the disk lies entirely on one tile?

Tags: probability

I am reading this problem of the ninth edition of Probability and Statistical Inference written by by Robert Hogg, Elliot Tanis and Dale Zimmerman. According to the explanation, the probability is 4/16 = 1/4. In my perspective, the answer should be the area of a disk divided by the area of a tile. The probabiity would be pi/16. Would you agree? Disagree? Thank you for your wisdom!

The problem is in the chapter 1, section 1.1 of the book. I am wondering if that is the reason why the authors put 1/4.

Here is the problem:

[image]

Comment: The explanation given is correct and pretty self-explanatory. If you are confused about the given explanation, please explain exactly what confuses you. Regarding your attempt, perhaps it would be a good idea to clearly explain why you believe the answer should be "area of disk divided by area of tile," and maybe along the way you can find why your argument is not correct.

Comment: @angryavian Would the explanation be that the center of the disk must in an area that is 1/4 of the tile?

Comment: Sounds like you are confused why the shape is a square and not another disk? think of it as a point which must be minimum of 1 inches from sides of square. You think about it the point must be in a smaller square inside the larger square (1 inch from 2 sides is 2 inches). Then edge or boundary of the object is defined by points less than 1 which happens to be a circle of diameter 2, just as needed.

Comment: @marshalcraft Thank you! I think that I understand now why is 1/4.